# Can an Aggregate Root factory method return a command instead of publishing an event?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, aggregateroot, axon

In Vaughn Vernon's `Implementing Domain-Driven Design` book, he described the use of factory method in an Aggregate Root. One example was that of a `Forum` aggregate root which had `startDiscussion` factory method which returned a `Discussion` aggregate root.

```
public class Forum extends Entity  {

    ...

    public Discussion startDiscussion(
      DiscussionId aDiscussionId, Author anAuthor, String aSubject) {

        if (this.isClosed()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Forum is closed.");
        }

        Discussion discussion = new Discussion(
          this.tenant(), this.forumId(), aDiscussionId, anAuthor, aSubject);

        DomainEventPublisher.instance().publish(new DiscussionStarted(...));

        return discussion;    
    }
```

How would one implement this factory pattern in an event sourcing system, specifically in Axon?

**I believe conventionally**, it may be implemented in this way:

`StartDiscussionCommand` -> `DiscussionStartedEvent` -> `CreateDiscussionCommand` -> `DiscussionCreatedEvent`

We fire a `StartDiscussionCommand` to be handled by the `Forum`, `Forum` then publishes a `DiscussionStartedEvent`. An external event handler would catch the `DiscussionStartedEvent`, convert it, and fire a `CreateDiscussionCommand`. Another handler would instantiate a `Discussion` using the `CreateDiscussionCommand` and `Discussion` would fire a `DiscussionCreatedEvent`.

**Alternatively**, can we instead have:
`StartDiscussionCommand` -> `CreateDiscussionCommand` -> `DiscussionCreatedEvent`

We fire `StartDiscussionCommand`, which would trigger a command handler and invoke `Forum`'s startDiscussion() method that will return the `CreateDiscussionCommand`. The handler will then dispatch this `CreateDiscussionCommand`. Another handler receives the command and use this to instantiate `Discussion`. `Discussion` would then fire the `DiscussionCreatedEvent`.

The first practice involves 4 DTOs, whilst the second one involves only 3 DTOs.

Any thoughts on which practice should be preferred? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: `DiscussionCreatedCommand` is `DiscussionCreatedEvent`

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Thanks for pointing out the clerical error. I've fixed it.

Comment: I whould choose first solution but without `CreateDiscussionCommand` and `DiscussionCreatedEvent`. Do you really need those? I believe that `DiscussionStartedEvent` could be sufficient

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU You may be right. I forgot that Axon had an AggregateFactory (which accepts a first event) I could probably use to instantiate an aggregate. I'll try it out first and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it?  Did it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach to a problem like this, is to consider your aggregates (in fact, the entire system) as a black box first. Just look at the API.

```
Given a Forum (that is not closed),
When I send a StartedDiscussionCommand for that forum,
A new Discussion is started.
```

But also

```
Given a Forum that was closed
When I send a CreateDiscussionCommand for that forum,
An exception is raised
```

Note that the API you suggested is too technical. In 'real life', you don't create a discussion, you start one.

This means state of the forum is involved in the creation of the discussion. So ideally (when looking into the black box), such a scenario would be implemented in the Forum aggregate, and apply an event which represents the creation event for a Discussion aggregate. This is under the assumption that other factors require the Forum and Discussion to be two distinct aggregates.

So you don't really want the Command handler to return/send a command, you want that handler to make a decision on whether to create an aggregate or not.

Unfortunately, Axon doesn't support this feature, yet. At the moment, Axon cannot apply an event that belongs to another aggregate, through its regular APIs.

However, there is a way to get it done. In Axon 3, you don't have to `apply` an Event, you can also publish one directly to the Event Bus (which in the case of Event Sourcing would be an Event Store implementation). So to implement this, you could directly publish a DomainEventMessage that contains a DiscussionCreatedEvent. The ID for the discussion can be any UUID and the sequence number of the event is 0, as it is the creation event of the discussion.

Comment: Do you mean that I should inject the EventStore into the `Forum` aggregate root?

Comment: I have an idea on how I can go about this. Thanks for the insight. I'll give an update soon.

Comment: Sorry it took awhile, but yes I managed to make your suggestion work. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> Any thoughts on which practice should be preferred?

The motivation for a command is to direct the application to update the book of record.  A command that you don't expect to produce an event is pretty weird.

That is, if your flow is

```
Forum.startDiscussion -> []
Discussion.create -> [ DiscussionCreated ]
```

One is bound to ask why the Forum is involved at all?

```
if (this.isClosed()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Forum is closed.");
}
```

This here is an illusion -- we're looking at the state of the Forum at some arbitrary point in the past to process the Discussion command.  In other words, after this check, the state of *Forum* could change, and our processing in *Discussion* would not know.  So it would be just as correct to make this check when validating the command, or by checking the read model from within Discussion.

(Everything we get from the book of record is a representation of the past; it has to be, in order to already be in the book of record for us to read.  The only moment that we act in the present is that point where we update the book of record.  More precisely, its at the moment of the write that we discover if the assumptions we've made about the past still hold.  When we write the changes to Discussion, we are proving that Discussion hasn't changed since we read the data; but that tells us nothing of whether Forum has changed).

What command->command looks like is an api compatibility adapter; in the old API, we used a Forum.startDiscussion command.  We changed the model, but continue to support the old command for backwards compatibility.  It would all still by synchronous with the request.

That's a real thing (we want the design to support aggressive updates to the model without requiring that clients/consumers be constantly updating), but it's not a good fit for your process flow.

Comment: Read the code carrefully: `throw new IllegalStateException("Forum is closed.");`